# Webservices invalid header guid exception

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a GUID & token to be passed whenever a webmethod (webservice) is called, from client app that is consuming the webservice.

1. Client app throws an `"Error:undefined"` javascript error & it gives this as exception when viewed via firebug.

> ```
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
> ```
>
> Invalid GUID Header.
>
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapMessage.RunExtensions(SoapExtension[]
>   extensions, Boolean thrownException)
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.CreateServerInstance()
>   at
>
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
>   at
>
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcesSRequest()

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Once the user logged in , the application has been kept idle for more than 12 hrs, after which when clicked got that error. I don't do any manipulation with GUIDs.